# Does k consistency always imply (k - 1) consistency?

Tags: linear-algebra

From Russell-Norvig:

> A CSP is strongly k-consistent if it is k-consistent and is also (k − 1)-consistent, (k − 2)-consistent, . . . all the way down to 1-consistent.

How can a CSP be k-consistent without being (k - 1)-consistent? I can't think of any counter example for this case. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Define P as a CSP where X, Y are the variables, domain of both is {1,2,3,4} and conditions in normal form are:

1. node-condition X<4
2. arc-condition X=Y

P is 2-consistent (arc consistent) because for any X value it is possible to find a Y value that fulfills the arc-condition X=Y.

However, P is not 1-consistent (node-consistent) because exist a X value (X=4) that can not fulfill the node condition x<4.

For these reasons, this problem is 2-consistent but not strongly 2-consistent.

Obviously, it is straightforward to convert this example in a strongly 2-consistent problem, just reducing the domain to {1,2,3}.